# WPF Button in a ListView, how do I tell which button was clicked

Tags: wpf-controls

WPF 3.5
I have a ListView for which the XAML looks like so

```
<ListView Name="ListView_FileAttachments">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
                    <GridView.Columns>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Type"></GridViewColumn>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="File Name"></GridViewColumn>                            
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Security">
                            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Button Content="Set Restrictions" Click="Restrictions_Clicked"></Button>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>

                        </GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView.Columns>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>              
        </ListView>
```

When I Click on a button in an individual cell how do I tell which button was clicked ( to be clear though I am interested in the ListView Item that this button belongs to because what I really want to do is retrieve the value of another column in that row )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **DataContext** of the button (i.e. the sender for the event) will be the dataitem from the listview's Items. If you want the container (i.e. the ListViewItem) then you can either walk up the visual tree (e.g. using **VisualTreeHelper.GetParent**) until you hit the ListViewItem or you can use the **ListView_FileAttachments.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem** passing in the data item (which you get from the DataContext of the button).